# Need the "msacli.exe" file for monitoring P2000 SAN. IOPS values needed

Tags: monitoring, hp, storage-area-network, iops, hp-modular-smart-array

Hi i need some performance stats from our MSA p2000 SAN. The Problem is that i want to have the values i get when i connect via SSH and use the command "show vdisk-statistics". This command shows me the IOPS for all vdisks. But this are values just from the actual moment. I want to have some values over a period of time...

The Webinterface of the p2000 doesn't provide me this values.

Now i found some tips on the internet like here:
http://www.remilner.co.uk/prtg-monitoring-a-hp-p2000-g3-msa/

this would be a great solution for me, but the problem is, that i can not find the msacli.exe anywhere. Does anyone know where to get this file? I didn't found it on official HP sites...

EDIT: HP-Support told me that this tool isn't available anymore... :-/
I also tried to get the values via "POSH-SSH" and Powershell and "plink.exe" but POSH-SSH gets an error and in plink.exe i don't know how i can save the console output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really not going to be able to get this information out of an MSA or P2000 storage array. At least, no historical information. You could parse the output from the SSL CLI at regular intervals, but that's not ideal.

This is just a disadvantage of the platform.

You may want to check with the OEM, [DotHill](https://www.dothill.com) to see if anything is available from their side.

Comment: ok. thank you ewwhite. I think i try to parse the output... as you said, not ideal, but better than nothing... :-/

Answer (score 1):

ewwhite was right. For those how want to see how i get the values in PRTG (Networkmonitoring) here are my scripts. I know the following is NOT very nice and seems to be very "froggy", but for me it works and i only need values over a periode of about a week...

The ssh connection is established via "plink.exe" a smart comand line tool as a part of the SSH program "Tutty". P.s. Do first connection manually to "accept" the new "ssh fingerprint"

**get_msa_statistics.bat**

```
@echo off
D:
cd D:\p2000-iops
(.\plink.exe -ssh -l USER -pw PASSWORD -m .\empty.txt IP <.\execute.txt)>output.txt 2>>&1
```

**empty.txt** --> is really a empty file but is needed...

**output.txt** --> the output from SSH Shell.

**execute.txt** --> put in here SAN commands

```
set cli-parameters pager disabled
set cli-parameters api-embed
show vdisk-statistics
```

**p2000-iops.ps1** --> This script is startet every minute from PRTG Monitoring (Custom Sensor)

```
#start the ssh session to get the row output data
& D:\p2000-iops\get_msa_statistics.bat

$file = "D:\p2000-iops\output.txt"
$src = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern "IOPS"

$iops = @()
foreach ($i in $src){
    $iops += $i.ToString()
}

for ($i=0; $i -lt $iops.Length; $i++){
    $tmp = $iops[$i].Split(">")
    $iops[$i] = $tmp[1]

    $tmp = $iops[$i].split("<")
    $iops[$i] = $tmp[0]

    $iops[$i] = [int]$iops[$i]
}

$sum = $iops | Measure-Object -sum
$sum = $sum.Sum

write-host "<prtg>
<result><channel>IOPS vDISK1</channel><value>$($iops[0])</value></result>
<result><channel>IOPS vDISK2</channel><value>$($iops[1])</value></result>
<result><channel>IOPS Total</channel><value>$sum</value></result>
</prtg>"
```

The "write-host" expression is in the format which is needed by PRTG. In PRTG i have now a graphical overview over all my vDISC IOPS (in my case 6 values. the script above is truncated by me) and also the Total sum of IOPS...

Hope this will help some others with similar problems. In this way you can also get other MSA P2000 SSH values in our prevered monitoring tool.

PRTG screenshot:
[image: PRTG graph]

Comment: np. But a short question what would be correct to mark as "solution"? Because your post brought me the solution...

Comment: I worked at a hosting firm that bought dozens of these P2000 units, and we were surprised that there was no tooling available for reporting. So we searched for a solution, but ended up giving up on the platform and using something a bit more transparent. The answer mark is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [HP MSA2000 Monitoring Management Pack](ftp://15.216.110.21/ftp2/pub/softlib2/software1/sc-windows/p1993940870/v70415/cp015535.exe), msacli.exe is the part of this pack. Also you can use SNMP for monitor perfomance of HP MSA.

Comment: i already found this link. Problem is that your link is dead. I think HP disabled all official sources to this tool...